# MATLAB - Access vector from a structure

Tags: matlab, data-structures, cell-array

I have a 1x4 structure called

```
Fruitbasket=struct('apples',{[1] [2] [3] [4]},'bananas',[],'berries',[],'melons',[])
```

I'm not sure how to get `Fruitbaskets.apples` in vector form (e.g., `[1 2 3 4]`).

All I get for `Fruitbaskets.apples` is `ans=1;ans=2;ans=3;ans=4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** It looks like you want to have an array of structures. A very simple solution of catching this values is plainly looping:

```
for ii=1:size(Fruitbasket,2)
    app(ii)=Fruitbasket(ii).apples; % or getfield(Fruitbasket(ii),'apples');
end
```

---

That is because you are creating an array of structures, not a structure with arrays!

```
Fruitbasket=struct('apples',{[1] [2] [3] [4]},...)
```

Creates 4 Fruitbaskets, each of them with a single number. You can verify this by doing `Fruitbasket(2).apples`. If you want the field `apples` to have an array, do not define it as a `cell array` bus as a `vector`. Cell arrays are defined with `{}` and dovecots with `[]`. The following will create a single struct with a vector in `apples`:

```
Fruitbasket=struct('apples',[1 2 3 4],'bananas',[],'berries',[],'melons',[])
```

Comment: actually sorry my fault. I forgot to mention, I DO have 4 fruitbaskets. I still would like to achieve Fruitbaskets.apples  in vector form

Comment: yep, that worked. What if it was [A] [B] [C] [D] instead of [1] [2] [3] [4]...error: 'Conversion to cell from char is not possible'. I tried mat2cell but nope

Comment: @Agnel what is `A`? you mean `'A'` as a string?

Comment: yep, just a few grades. 'F' 'D' 'B' 'A'

Comment: @Agnel well.... that works without any problem with the for loop.... In fact, that error makes no sense with my code, because there are no cell arrays anywere, so there should not be error of "conversion to cell"

Comment: Fruitbasket=struct('apples',{['F'] ['D'] ['B'] ['A']},'bananas',[],'berries',[],'melons',[]); Plain Loop - for ii=1:size(Result,2)
a(ii)=(Fruitbasket(ii).apples); 
end

Comment: @Agnel yep, it works (I changed `result` to `Fruitbasket` and removed the `Plain Loop` that is not a MATLAB command.

Comment: :( why not me? :'(

Comment: @Agnel is `a` a cell array? try adding `a=[]` before the loop

Comment: It's all good with numeric values. But not for any chars like 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'

Comment: @Agnel you already said that yes. And I repeat. its good with chars. `Fruitbasket=struct('apples',{['A'] ['B'] ['C'] ['D']},'bananas',[],'berries',[],'melons',[]); a=[]; for ii=1:size(Fruitbasket,2); a(ii)=(Fruitbasket(ii).apples); end`

Comment: sorry, my bad. I see you will get [A B C D] for a. I keep getting [ 65 66 67 68] for some reason

Comment: @Agnel which is Exactly the same. Read a bit about ASCII

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks heaps. That's all I needed! :)